# How do you present a different PKI client certificate to a server once you have already presented one, in Firefox?

Tags: certificate, pki

When I visit a website that requires PKI client certificates Firefox will allow the user to select which certificate to present.

How do you present a different PKI client certificate to a server once you have already presented one, in Firefox?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This [blogpost](https://www.progclub.org/blog/2012/03/16/clearing-ssl-session-state-in-firefox/) describes what you are looking for:

> To clear your SSL session state in Firefox choose History -> Clear
>   Recent History... and then select "Active Logins" and click "Clear
>   Now". Then the next time you connect to your SSL server Firefox will
>   prompt for which certificate to use.

Comment: not useful for me

Answer (score 11):

Since this was the highest result on google:

The location seems to have been changed (Tested on Firefox 101). You can now find the setting in:

`Options` > `Privacy & Security` > `Security` > `View Certificates...` > Tab `Authentication Decisions`.

Here you can remove every single decision for the selected client certificate.

Comment: Xref here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72971260/1315009 and given credit.

Comment: This should be marked as answer! 

Answer (score 0):

And just for completeness, as i was searching for the **easy way**, **without deleting everything**:

- `Open` the specific url
- Click on the certificate information next to the url (The `Lock-Sign`)
- You can directly click on `Delete Cookies and Website Data`
- Select the specific (sub-)domain you want to reset