# How do you clear an SSL State in a Firefox > version 20 web browser?

Tags: firefox, certificate, pki

How do you clear an SSL State in a Firefox > version 20 web browser?

When browsing PKI-enabled websites, the session will timeout so ofter. To re-enable your session in Internet Explorer your Clear SSL state by going to Tools>Internet Options>Content(tab)>Clear SSL State.

It used to be you could do "tools | start private browsing" then stop it and reload the page and Firefox would clear the SSL state.

In version 21 and above this appears to be missing?  Is there any way to do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you present a different PKI client certificate to a server once you have already presented one, in Firefox?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24040662/how-do-you-present-a-different-pki-client-certificate-to-a-server-once-you-have)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have found on two different sites the same method and it worked for me too:
Go to "History" -> "Clear Recent History..." and then select "Active Logins" and click "Clear Now".

(Source: https://www.progclub.org/blog/2012/03/16/clearing-ssl-session-state-in-firefox/ and http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=38&t=468067)