# How can I choose a different client certificate in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, pki

When I choose a client certificate in Firefox (or cancel choosing none), Firefox seems to remember this decision even though I've told it to ask me every time. I understand that it'd be useless for Firefox to ask me *every page load*, so of course it's remembering my decision for the length of whatever it thinks of as a session, but how can I change that selection or close that session? It's not a per-tab decision...

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you present a different PKI client certificate to a server once you have already presented one, in Firefox?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24040662/how-do-you-present-a-different-pki-client-certificate-to-a-server-once-you-have)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to clear SSL session state of your browser. Take a look at [my anwer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24041645/3325704):

> in Firefox choose History -> Clear Recent History... and then select "**Active Logins**" and click "Clear Now".

Comment: I had to also check to clear "Site Preferences" in FF 84.0.2. Then it works.

Comment: Can confirm Eugene comment FFox 88.0.1 Site Preferences has to be checked also

Comment: I can confirm that clearing "Site Preferences" does the job, "Active Logins" no longer needs to be checked.

Comment: In Firefox 96 there is no "Site preferences", but it is called "Site settings"

Answer (score 17):

With the selected answer (2015), you clear "all data since the last XXXX hours". Nevertheless, as per this answer (2020) from @Luke https://stackoverflow.com/a/65303926/1315009 you can pick what decissions to remove, site per site.

`Settings` > `Privacy & Security` > `Security` > `View Certificates...` > Tab `Authentication Decisions` => Pick from the list and delete.

Tested on Firefox `v102.0.1` & `v103.0.2` and it works.

### hint

Inside settings type `cert` in the search and you get there in a split-second:

[image: Shortcut to certs]

Answer (score 7):

The most straightforward way to indicate Firefox that you want to be asked every time for the right certificate is to adjust the `security.default_personal_cert` property in "Advanced Preferences". I have not found a way to do it through the "Options" menu, which is the recommended and safe way to change your Firefox preferences.

How to proceed:

1. Access Firefox's "Advanced Preferences" by opening a new tab and typing `about:config` into the address bar
2. Firefox will display a "Proceed with caution" warning. Click on "Accept the risk and continue".
3. On the "Search preference name" bar, type `security.default_personal_cert`
4. Set the value of that property to `Ask Every Time`
5. Close the tab (make sure that you do not change anything else)

You are done. If a website needs a certificate, you will now be asked to choose one from the list instead of having it automatically selected.

(Note: I am using Firefox 85.0 (64-bit) on Windows 10. If I am not wrong, previous versions of Firefox allowed to change that preference from "Options".)