# How to get Chrome/Firefox to prompt me for certificates and not default to my previous used certificate

Tags: ssl, browser, certificate, webserver

For my REST requests, I am using certificates to connect to a backend Liberty web server.  I get prompted with a list of acceptable certificates, and I select one.   This works fine.  I can do my work.

I logoff from the server because I want to use a different certificate (which gives me different authority)
However I automatically get reconnected to the site using the previous certificate, I do not get the list of available certificates presented to me.
The only way I have found of doing it is to close down the browser, and restart it.
I think the sessionid is being sent up, and reused.

Can I get this to work?  It may just be a browser setting, or I may need to change the backend.  Ive tried closing the socket, and session.invalidate().

I think this is the opposite of most problems where people do not want to get prompted for the certificate

Comment: In my Firefox preferences, in "Security & Privacy", completely at bottom, I have: "When a server requests your personal certificate" and then two options: 1) Select one automatically 2) Ask you every time.   Did you select the second option?

Comment: Also, did you see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27864553/how-can-i-choose-a-different-client-certificate-in-firefox and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24040662/how-do-you-present-a-different-pki-client-certificate-to-a-server-once-you-have ? But they are from a few years back...

Comment: Patrick - perfect just what I was looking for thank you.  It works!   I'll look in Chrome for a similar function.

Comment: I found a Chromium discussion [here](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=90454#c18) where they discuss how it would be a good idea to do what Firefox has.  It looks like Chromium does not have this capability on unix.   I see people explaining how to do it on Windows.